# Getting undefined is not a function while array destructing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function foo([a,b,c]) {
  console.log(a,b,c);
}

foo(1,2,3);
```

Why above code throws undefined is not a function?

Comment: This will work `foo(...[a,b,c])`

Comment: You cannot use an array as an argument in your function construct.

Comment: I'm wondering the same, it seems JS does something diff when it comes to the function params.
This code throws the correct error.
```js
function foo(data) {
    const [b] = data;
}
a()
```
You code is bringing confusion bc you called your function incorrectly.

It should be foo([1,2,3]);

Answer (score 4):

You could spread the arguments and assign the variables inside the function

```js
const foo = (...args) => {
  const [a,b,c] = args
  console.log(a,b,c);
}

foo(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question is "undefined is not a function", what is undefined here?

Comment: Because you can't make arguments an array

Comment: @john33 If you run your question snippet code you'll see the error "TypeError: (destructured parameter) is not iterable".

Comment: @charlietfl, your code works fine. I was talking about a different error message in the OP's question code from the one he reported.

Comment: @Andy, it shows Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Huh. Maybe I've got a fancy version of Firefox that no-one else does.

Answer (score 4):

Because the js engine didn't match any iterable object from the parameters.

Look at this example

```js
function foo([a, b, c]) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

// This time, we are passing an array which is iterable
foo([1, 2, 3]);
```

An alternative is using the Spread syntax and then the function `apply` to pass the whole set of params as separated params to the function `console.log`.

```js
function foo(...params) {
  console.log.apply(undefined, params);
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Got a solution but still don't understand it properly

`function foo([a, b, c]) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

foo('1', '2', '3');`